# Worklight Hybrid application with Xtify console for push notification

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, xtify

Please help me, I have created one work light hybrid application in eclipse after that i have to integrate that application with "XTIFY" console for push notification how?

If you have any guides please share with me for this or if you have any sample coding please share with me.

I have tried lot, i'm new to work light, please try to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question to which Worklight/MobileFirst version you are using... You can find instructions for different versions, here:  https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification/ibm-worklight/

Assuming you're using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 (the latest version supposed by Xtify), you can follow these basic steps:

1. Create a new IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation project or use an existing project.
2. Download the latest version of the IBM Push Notification Worklight package and expand the zip file.
3. It is recommended to update to the current iOS and Android SDKs at the time you start developing your app; however, the packages for IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation are compatible with earlier versions.
4. Copy ./js/MobilePush.js to ./apps/{app}/common/js.
5. Optional (for debugging): Copy content of ./js/main.js from the plug-in package to the end of the file in your project: ./apps/{app}/common/js/main.js.
6. Edit ./apps/{project}/common/index.html by copying the following:

   ```
   <script src="js/messages.js">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MobilePush.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkForMessages, false);
           document.addEventListener("resume", checkForMessages, false);
   ```

You then need to follow platform-specific instructions.